# Startup Qt Qml based app

Tags: qt, qml, buildroot

I would like to know how to make startup qt qml based app with buidroot. I've already added my app as a package in menuconfig,but when image is created(making image for rpi2) and booted via SD Card only colorful screen is showing,and I'm assuming my kernel doesn't even load up.Makefile for app was made with Qt build.
Also,I would like to know how to boot my rpi2 even faster and are there any changes that can be made in my Buildroot configuration to assure that.
Thank you in advance..

App .mk file in buildroot package:

```
FRTDisplay_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = /home/igor/build-FRTDisplay-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_GCC_64bit-Debug
FRTDisplay_OVERRIDE_RSYNC = yes

define FRTDISPLAY_BUILD_CMDS
        $(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)
endef

define FRTDISPLAY_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
        if ! [ -d "$(TARGET_DIR)/bin/" ]; then \
                mkdir -p $(TARGET_DIR)/bin/; \
        fi
        $(INSTALL) -D -m 0755 $(@D)/build-FRTDisplay-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_GCC_64bit-Debug $(TARGET_DIR)/bin/
endef

define FRTDISPLAY_CLEAN_CMDS
        $(MAKE) -C $(@D) clean
endef

define FRTDISPLAY_UNINSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
        rm -f $(TARGET_DIR)/bin/build-FRTDisplay-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_GCC_64bit-Debug
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

Init script in app source folder:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
  start)
    /home/igor/build-FRTDisplay-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_GCC_64bit-Debug
    ;;
  stop)
    exit 1
    ;;
  *)
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I used rpi2 defconfig,and this is a list of altered options in menuconfig:

```
-default arhitecture
-default toolchain
-uclib
-enable c++
-enable compiler link time opt support
-enable mmu support
sys config
-enable root login
-enable busybox default shell
-disable getty
-enable remount root
-disable network interfaces
kernel
-enable linux kernel
target packages
-install watchdog daemon
-enable zip
hardware handling
-enable rpi-userland
-enable start vcfield
graphic
-enable qt5
-enable gui module
-enable widgets module
-enable opengl support
-enable opengl module
-enable eglfs
-default graphical platform(eglfs)
-enable qtbase,fontconfig,gif,png,jpg,dbus,icu,tslib,qt5 declarative,qt5graphicaleffects,qt5imageformatting,qtquickcontrols,qtquickcontrols2,qt5script,qt5sensors,qt5serialports,qt5xmlpatterns
```

My app is purely display app,I don't need networking or any other network-related fetaure in my buildroot configuration.
ps. Sorry for js code snippets,I'm new to stackoverflow questions :)

Comment: Did you check [Boot to Qt Software Stack](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtfordevicecreation-5.11/qtb2-index.html)?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot download it because I use an opensource version of Qt